# Batch Error:The syntax of the command is incorrect

Tags: batch-file

I am running a Batch File the first command executes the AWK Script and the second command checks the generated file of AWK Script.When I run the each command as separate Batch File it is working fine and if I combine both the command the AWK Script is executed successfully but the file checking is giving "The syntax of the command is incorrect"

Below is the Batch File

## Executing AWK Script

```
echo off
set arg1=%1
set arg2=%2
set arg3=%3
set arg4=%4
set arg5=%5
set arg6=%6
set arg7=%7
shift
shift
shift
shift
shift
shift
shift
%arg1% -v DF=%arg2% -v DFP=%arg3% -v DFPP=%arg4% -v DFPO=%arg5% -f%arg6% %arg7%
```

## Checking File Exists

```
if exist "D:/Sample/OutPut.txt"(
echo file exists
) else (
echo file doesn't exist
)
```

Note:If I run separately File Checking in a batch file it works fine,but If I combine in a single file It is giving error.Help me to solve the issue.

Thanks & Regards
Prakash

Comment: First tip: remove (or comment-out) the `echo off` line so you can see which command it doesn't like.  If this doesn't lead you to the solution, post the complete file _as it is when causing problems_ together with the command-line you use to run it -- "_if I combine in a single file_" isn't precise enough.

Comment: Add space before `(` in the `if` statement.